# Check a lot of SNS whether the handle is already used or not

Tags: gratis, web-apps

I search for the web service on which you type in whatever handle you want to use, and then get immediately the list of SNS that shows whether the name is already used or not. For example, if you type in `@mike_and_jason`, you get something like the follows:

- Twitter: already used
- Instagram: available
- GitHub: available
- Snapchat: already used
- Service XXX: your name is invalid; the service doesn't permit the underscore.

I remember I found such site 2 years ago, but forgot about it and have not been able to get to it while searching...